# Rails Tutorial: Unable to autoload constant SessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm going through Michael Hartl's rails tutorial and all is well, but I seem to have borked something and I can't figure out where (partially thanks to my horrendously sloppy git commits)

> LoadError: Unable to autoload constant SessionsController, expected /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb to define it

Inside of `~/workspace/sample_app/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb`:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      flash[:success] = "Successfully logged in!"
      redirect_back_or(user)
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Invalid email or password"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logout if logged_in?
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

The test in question that is failing is:

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end    
end
```

Everything I'm digging up is telling me it's a case sensitivity issue, but the snake case and camel case look correct to me. It was working fine earlier but now it's not, and I'm really unsure where I could've gone wrong.

Other integration tests that rely on the `SessionsController` are also failing, when referencing the `sessions_helper.rb` file. But I figure failing on a get `:new` would be the right place to start fixing it.

Comment: Did you change the name of the controller lately? Or move the file? Can you also please include `sessions_helper.rb`? Does removing it solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with Cloud9's online IDE.  For whatever reason it was displaying the sessions_controller.rb file with everything in it, when it fact (again, for reasons I do not understand) it was blank.  Closing the workspace on all machines and reopening it showed the file as blank, and copy+pasting the controller code in the original post solved the issue.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I also had to clear my cookies to make it work.